# Can there be "identity-like" mappings that do not involve the identity element in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working with the definition of an identity from Pinter's intro book on abstract algebra. He writes as follows:

[image]

I understand that if an operation has an identity it must be unique, which can be seen letting $e$ and $f$ be identities and noting that $e = e*f$ and $e*f=f$, so $e = f$. However — and I'm not sure how to word this — can there be *specific* non-identity elements on which another element has identity-like action?

Consider a later problem in Pinter's book where we identify that the operation

$$(a, b) * (c, d) = (ac, bc + d), \quad \text{on the set } \left(\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\right) \times \mathbb{R}$$

is a group with the identity element $e = (1, 0)$. But if we add the deleted zero back into the first coordinate's domain and do the same checks on that reformed $\mathbb{R}^2$ we run into the motivation for my question. I am not concerned with whether the operation still defines a group — it definitely does not since the inverse breaks — I am concerned with whether the identity still holds. It's still clear that $(1, 0)$ works for all elements in the new domain but it's not clear if it's acceptable that a specific element now has other identity-like relationships, like

$$(0, 0) * (x, 0) = (0, 0) = (x, 0) * (0, 0) \tag{$\star$}$$

Because there is still only one element as Pinter describes — one that works for *every* element in $\mathbb{R}^2$. My instinct is that the identity still holds, but I was reviewing an answer here: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~mstemper2/Math/Pinter/Chapter03B, problem 2 & 3, and the author states that $(\star)$ breaks uniqueness. So, to what part of the definition is uniqueness applied? It sounds like author of the linked answer has taken the converse as the definition.

---

**Edit:** Due to comments let me try to restate my problem more succinctly:

For a set and and a binary operation on that set, if there is/are some element(s) $a$ such that $xa=ax=x$ for many, possibly infinite choices of $x$, but only one element $e$ such $xe=ex=x$ for every $x$, is the property of the *uniqueness* of $e$ in the context of groups violated? What about for general sets with binary operations?

---

**Edit2:** I am utterly convinced that for a group

1. There is only one identity element $e$
2. There is no other element $e'$ in that group such that $xe'=e'x=x$

But I am not convinced that these statements are equivalent for operations on sets, only that they happen to coincide for a group. Based on Pinter's definition, I think that an identity for an operation on a set can be unique (statement 1), yet there may still be elements $e'$ in such that $xe'=e'x=x$ for some value of $x$ but not all. So in the linked answer when the author states

> So this operation does not have a unique identity element.

I become confused because it isn't true. I don't see how it could ever be true. Of course this is probably just a quickly typed answer and the answerer meant to say *group* instead of *operation*, but the comments below are making me second guess this.

Comment: $(0,0)$ is what is called a "zero element" (unsurprisingly). In a semigroup $S$, a zero element is an element $0$ such that $0x=x0=0$ for all $x\in S$. That does *not* look like an "identity-like relationship" to me... it looks like a relationship where $0$ overwhelms everything it comes in contact with... the very opposite of an identity.

Comment: Agreed, so then the linked answer incorrect in its reasoning?

Comment: There is no incorrect reasoning in either problem 2 or 3. There is no lack of uniqueness in problems 2. Problem 3 is noting that *in that set*, there are many possible solutions to the equation $x_1e_1=x_1$. So if you try to proceed as in the previous problem, you will find that for some elements $\mathbf{x}$, there are many possible elements $\mathbf{e}$ that satisfy $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{x}$. If this happens for even a *single* element, then the resulting structure is not a group. What exactly is it you think is wrong about that reasoning? Your post seems to wander all over the place

Comment: I find the reasoning to be off in the sense that, as you say, "for some elements $x$, there are many possible elements $e$ that satisfy $xe=x$" which does not contradict that there may be a *particular* unique element $e$ such that $xe=x$ for *all* elements $x$.

Comment: In a group, any equation of the form $ax=b$ has a **unique** solution namely $x=a^{-1}b$. If $xf=x$, then $x^{-1}xf = x^{-1}x$, the left hand side is $f$, and the right hand side is $e$.  So the only possible solution is $e$. If you can find more than one solution for any particular $e$, then what you have is not a group. In a group, what you are positing is, in fact, utterly impossible.

Comment: Your examples are **semigroups**. In semigroups, all sorts of things can happen, including the existence of zero elements and multiple one-sided inverses. But in a **group**, for any $x$, the **only** thing you can multiply $x$ by to get $x$ is the identity element of the group. That is an assertion about a single $x$, not about what needs to happen to all elements. Once you have a group, there can be no solution to $ax=a$ except $x=e$, for any particular $a$.

Comment: So, you've shown that for groups, of which I'm half concerned, that the identity element has to be utterly unique, no other element can can have identity-like behavior, that is no other element $a$ satisfies $xa=ax=x$ for multiple values of $x$. But the other half of which I'm concerned is whether the existence of an identity element in a set with a binary operation implies that element's uniqueness. As described in the edit to my post. In your method you use the uniqueness of the inverse, but then don't I first need a proof that inverses are unique?

Comment: In a group, no other element $a$ but the identity can satisfy $xa=x$ for **any** element $x$; not even *one*, let alone “multiple values of $x$.” **Not one.**  In a *monoid*, it is possible to have elements $e’$ for which $xe’=x$ for *some* $x$ but not all, while still having a unqiue element $e$ such that $xe=x$ for *all* $x$.

Comment: Yet that's not the definition of a group, it's a consequence of its definition. The author I link to reasons "Since x1 could be 0, e1 = 1 is not a unique solution to x1e1 = x1. So this **operation** does not have a unique identity element." The bold is mine. The operation still has a unique identity element. As you describe for the monoid but not in the same way you refer to for a group. For groups the identity is ultra-unique, it's the only element that satisfies the definition of an identity element and the only element that can perform an identity-like action for any element at all.

Comment: If $X$ is a consequence of the definition of a group, and you have a structure in which you can prove that $X$ does not hold, then the structure is not a group. This is basic logic. I ask again: what is the problem?

Comment: Agreed. My problem is now decaying to: did the author of the linked answer word his answer incorrectly and secondly the ambiguity in what is meant by a uniqueness w.r.t an operation vs a group as far as the identity element is concerned.

Comment: The answer is: no, he did not; you are just misinterpreting it.

Comment: Are you sure? Because the operation in question does have a unique identity element. It's the only element that satisfies the definition of an identity given by Pinter.

Comment: It’s not a group because it does not have inverses for every element. We can verify that it is not a group because if it *was* a group, then there would be only one solution to $ax=a$, but there are multiple solutions for some $a$. Yes, I am sure. I’ve only been doing group theory for over a quarter of a century.

Comment: "It’s not a group because it does not have inverses for every element. We can verify that it is not a group because if it was a group, then there would be only one solution to =, but there are multiple solutions for some ." Agreed. But can you show me that the operation in question does not have unique identity element as defined by Pinter?

Comment: The structure in question is a **monoid**. It *has* a unique identity element. But *it’s not a group*. Which is the point of the problem.

Comment: You shouldn’t talk about something happening or not happening “in the context of groups” if what you have is **not** a group...

Comment: Understood. So you see no point of confusion for a beginning algebra student in an incorrect statement embedded in a correct answer (referencing the linked answer again).

Comment: There is no “incorrect statement embedded in a correct answer.” There *is* your misunderstanding of a correct statement, though.

Comment: I don't understand. So the structure in my post is a monoid, therefore it *does* have a unique identity element, but the answerer stating that "... this operation *does not* have a unique identity element."  isn't contradictory?

Comment: Yeah, I know. If I had Pinter's solutions I'd be using them.

Comment: So “the author” is at best confusing. You weren’t talking about Pinter, you were talking about some random electrical engineer saying things. The phrasing from our random electrical engineer is imprecise, but it does still work: there is no unique identity for a proper subset of elements, which is still a requirement in a group.

Comment: Now you're covering for your earlier comments. I say "did the author of the linked answer word his answer incorrectly?" and you say "The answer is: no, he did not; you are just misinterpreting it. " But now you say "The phrasing from our random electrical engineer is imprecise, but it does still work: there is no unique identity for a proper subset of elements, which is still a requirement in a group." You're weasling the correct answer out his statement. Beginner algebra students are not expected to reach your interpretation. I think it was just lazy answering by your "random engineer"

Comment: Not “my” random electrical engineer, but whatever. I still think you are reading more into what he said than what he actually said, and that you got overwrought by this misreading. But I have neither the need nor desire to force you to accurately apportion blame.

Comment: Sorry, your *titled* "random electrical engineer". I think I was confused by his writing but not *overwrought*. Would it be appropriate if I said you got "into a tizzy" over the comments? Not nice.

Comment: If you object to my characterization of your state of mind as incorrect, perhaps you will want to avoid making further mistakes in this thread by not performing the act you just objected to. I wasn’t “in a tizzy”, but I certainly am getting tired.

Comment: Object to your characterization of my state of mind? Come on man. While what you said was just a little jab, someone could easily call somebody something vile and follow it up with "If you object to my characterization of your state of mind as incorrect...". No objection required for your comment to be inappropriate. Then I asked you how you would feel if I did the same.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: The difficulty in communicating with you outweighed the benefit of your answers or insight overall. Nonetheless it reinforces my own confidence and intuitions. Reminds me a time one of my top professors insisted I was wrong about something and where I turned out to be right — just about a little undergrad inequality. Something inspiring in knowing that even the best can have moments of goof.

Answer (score 2):

From comments, I finally figured out where you were going... (or so I thought, my confidence undermined by subsequent comments while I was writing this...)

In a semigroup (a set with a binary associative operation), it is possible for you to have elements that act as identities for *some*, but not all, elements. This shows up in rings (whose multiplicative structure is just a semigroup or a monoid (a semigroup with an identity element) and not groups. For example, the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ contains a subring $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ that has an “internal multiplicative identity” $(1,0)$ that is however not the identity for the whole ring (which is $(1,1)$).

However, in a group this just doesn’t happen. There are many ways to that fact, but basically, if you have a group $G$, and you have an element $a\in G$, then the **only** element of the group that satisfies the equation $ax=a$ is $x=e$, the identity. No element can act as an “identity” for any particular element *except* the identity itself.

This is a consequence of the following well-known observation:

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a group. Then for each $a,b\in G$, there exist unique solutions $x,y\in G$ to the equations
$$\begin{align*}
ax &= b\\
\text{and }ya &=b.
\end{align*}$$

**Proof.** *Existence:* let $x=a^{-1}b$, and let $y=ba^{-1}$. Then $ax = a(a^{-1}b) = (aa^{-1})b = eb = b$, and $ya=(ba^{-1})a = b(a^{-1}a) = be = b$.

*Uniqueness:* Suppose that $x_0$ and $x_0’$ are both solutions to $ax=b$. Then $ax_0=b=ax_0’$. So $ax_0=ax_0’$. Multiplying on the left by $a^{-1}$, we get
$$x_0 = ex_0 = (a^{-1}a)x_0 = a^{-1}(ax_0) = a^{-1}(ax_0’) = (a^{-1}a)x_0’ = ex_0’ = x_0’.$$
Therefore, $x_0=x_0’$. The same argument shows the uniqueness of $y$, by multiplying on the right by $a^{-1}$. $\Box$

In fact, this is a defining characteristic of groups:

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a nonempty set with a binary associative operation such that for all $a,b\in G$, there exist unique solutions to the equations
$$\begin{align*}
ax & = b\\
ya &= b.
\end{align*}$$
Then $G$ is a group under the binary associative operation.

*Note:* In fact, you may drop the “uniqueness clause.

*Proof.* Pick $a\in G$. Let $e_a$ be a solution to $ax=a$; I use the subscript $a$ because at this point we are not sure that it works for every element of $G$. Similarly, for every $g\in G$, there is an element $e_g\in G$ such that $ge_g=g$. I claim that $e_g=e_a$ for all $a$.

To see that, let $g\in G$ be arbitrary. Then there is a solution to $ya=g$. Then $ge_a = (ya)e_a = y(ae_a) = ya = g$. Since both $e_a$ and $e_g$ are solutions, it follows from the uniqueness hypotheses that $e_a=e_g$. So there is a unique element $e\in G$ such that $ae=e$ for all $a\in G$.

Likewise, for each $a\in G$ there exists $a’\in G$ such that $aa’=e$, by solving $ax=e$.

I claim that $a’’=(a’)’=a$. Indeed, we have
$$a’ = a’e = a’(aa’) = (a’a)a’.$$
Therefore,
$$e = a’(a’’) = ((a’a)a’)a’’ = (a’a)(a’a’’) = (a’a)e = a’a.$$
But the only solution to $a’x=e$ is $a’’$, so $a=a’’$.

In particular, for every $a$, $aa’=a’a=e$.

Finally, we just need to show that $ea=a$ for all $a$. But
$$ea = (aa’)a = a(a’a) = ae = a,$$
so this follows. Thus, $G$ is a group. $\Box$

---

Now, in a semigroup/monoid it is possible for there to be elements $e’$ such that $xe’=x$ for *some*, but not all, elements $x$.

In fact, given any semigroup $S$, one can construct a new semigroup $S^1$ as follows: let the $e_0$ be something that is not an element of $S$. Let $S^1 = S\cup\{e_0\}$. Define an operation $\cdot$ on $S^1$ as follows:
$$x\cdot y = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
xy &\text{if }x,y\in S;\\
x &\text{if }y=e_0;\\
y &\text{if }x=e_0.
\end{array}\right.$$
It is easy to verify that $S^1$ is a monoid, and that $e_0$ is the identity of the monoid. This, *even if $S$ already had an identity*. If you perform this construction multiple times, you end up with a sequence $S\subsetneq S_1\subsetneq S_2\subsetneq S_3\subsetneq\cdots$ of monoids such that for each $j$ there is an element $e_j$ in $S_j$ that is **the** identity of $S_j$, but such that $e_j$ is not an identity for $S_{j+1}$.

In a **monoid** this can happen; but *only if it is not a group.* If it is a group, then this situation just cannot happen.

(A **monoid** is a set $M$, together with a binary associative operation such that there exists $e\in M$ such that $ae=ea=a$ for all $a\in M$; from the definition, it follows that this element $e$, called the identity of $M$, is unique.)

This is the reason why when we define “submonoid” of $M$ we require the subset $N$ to be a monoid *and contain the identity of $M$* (and why a “subring-with-identity” is required to contain the identity of the ring), and why a monoid homomorphism $f\colon M\to N$ is required to take the identity of $M$ to the identity of $N$.

---

Coming back to Pinter, the exercise in question is correct. Even though the semigroup with underlying set $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and operation $(a,b)(c,d) = (ac,bc+d)$ is a **monoid** (and thus has a unique identity element), the fact that it fails to satisfy the theorem above about uniqueness of solution to the equations $ax=a$ establishes immediately that it cannot be a group.

The monoid in question is not a group because not every element has an inverse. In fact, the elements that have no inverses are *precisely* the elements $a$ for which the equation $ax=a$ has multiple solutions, namely the elements $(a,b)$ with $a=0$. (If $ax=a$ and $a$ has an element $a’$ such that $a’a=e$ where $e$ is the monoid identity, then $ax=a$ implies $a’ax =a’a$, which implies $x=e$, giving the uniqueness. This is because the set of invertible elements of a monoid forms a group).

Comment: Many proofs about groups commonly skip over this very important step in the proof without mentioning it anywhere else in the text. I came across this in proofs about [subgroups and the identity element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547233/a-closed-finite-subset-of-a-group-is-subgroup), and your proof was extremely helpful for filling in the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

No, there cannot be *other* "identity-like" elements for a group. In other words for a group that has an identity element $e$ there can't be even one $e'$ such that $xe'=x$, but there can in other structures, as pointed out by Arturo Magidin in the comments.

So while the linked answer may be interpreted as correct for subtler reasons (again, see Magidin's comments), it does state something incorrect which is that the operation as defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no identity element. The opeation has the identity element pointed out in the post, and it is unique since no other elements $R^2$ satisfy Pinter's definition.